# Preserving relationships between entities when migrating with multiple DB contexts with entity relationships outside some contexts in EF Core

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I have multiple `DB contexts` that contain `DBSets` that have relationships between them. I can migrate each `DB context` separately. However I'm concerned that the relationships between the entities won't be preserved as I'm specifying which entities must be ignored in each context so that I don't allow `EntityFramework` to pull in all the `DBSets` that are related to one another.

How can I simultaneously migrate all the contexts so that `EntityFramework` can preserve the relationships between the entities?

So far the only solution I know of is to create a context that contains all the `DBSets` and use that context to do the migrations.